# Where is the NewForm, DispForm, and EditForm on SP 2019?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-foundation, modal-dialog, 2019, cewp

Trying to find out where the New, Disp, and Edit form pages are on SP 2019.  Migrating from 2016 to 2019 and we had some customized forms using JavaScript.  The 2016 pages used CEWP to add the JavaScript to the DispForm.aspx page.  It appears that the SP 2019 DispForm looks like or behaves like a MODAL form.  Is there a way to customize these new forms without SP Designer?

Comment: If you're working with Modern libraries/lists, those won't have New/Edit/DispForm and cannot be largely customized due to on-prem limitations.

Comment: Thanks Trevor.  That's what I thought because I don't see anyway to customize these forms unless I go Classic...Upvoted.

Comment: Yep, you'll have to go classic if you want that customization which of course can be done via the means you did so in 2016.